# How to show all users process [with date, parent id, user-name] in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I'm on Kubuntu but I dont want to use any other libs, I can use only linux functions.I know that theres a library http://procps.sourceforge.net/ but thats not the point. I want to printf a processes owned by logged user, show their date, parent-process id, and username,how to do it in C?

Comment: You could read the `/proc` filesystem.

Comment: Why not read the library that does this and see how they do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to scan the `/proc` folder. I'm going to give you an idea about how to start. Sorry but i got no time to full code your request =(

(Look [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) at the `/proc/[pid]/stat` section to discover how the stat file is formatted)

```
  while((dirEntry = readdir("/proc")) != NULL) 
  {

      // is a number? (pid)
      if (scanf(dirEntry->d_name, "%d", &dummy) == 1) 
      {
          // get info about the node (file or folder)
          lstat(dirEntry->d_name, &buf);

          // it must be a folder
          if (buf.st_mode != S_IFDIR)
              continue;

          // check if it's owned by the uid you need
          if (buf.st_uid != my_userid)
              continue;

          // ok i got a pid of a process owned by my user
          printf("My user own process with pid %d\n", dirEntry->d_name);

          // build full path of stat file (full of useful infos)
          sprintf(stat_path, "/proc/%s/stat", dirEntry->d_name;

          // self explaining function (you have to write it) to extract the parent pid
          parentpid = extract_the_fourth_field(stat_path);

          // printout the parent pid
          printf("parent pid: %d\n", parentpid);

          // check for the above linked manual page about stat file to get more infos
          // about the current pid
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`system("ps -aef | grep username");` will get all the processes owned by user.

Answer (score 1):

These info are stored in `/proc`: each process has its own directory there named as its PID.

You'll need to iterate over all these directories and collect the data you need. That's what `ps` does.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading from `/proc`. proc filesystem is the best filesystem implemented in Linux.

If not,you can consider writing a Kernel module which will implement your own system call(to obtain the list of current processes) so that it can be called from a user space program.

```
/* ProcessList.c 
    Robert Love Chapter 3
    */
    #include < linux/kernel.h >
    #include < linux/sched.h >
    #include < linux/module.h >

    int init_module(void)
    {
    struct task_struct *task;
    for_each_process(task)
    {
    printk("%s [%d]\n",task->comm , task->pid);
    }

    return 0;
    }

    void cleanup_module(void)
    {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning Up.\n");
    }
```

The code above is taken from the article [here](http://linuxgazette.net/133/saha.html) .